# Using Python, How can I hide a watermark inside another image using PIL?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-imaging-library, watermark

The watermark needs to be encoded by making pixels from the image ‘even’ where the
corresponding watermark pixel is black and ‘odd’ where the corresponding watermark
pixel is white.

Function `add_watermark` must take two parameters, an image file name, e.g.,
`StoryBridge.bmp`, and a watermark file name, e.g., `dog_watermark.bmp`,
and it must create a new image file, e.g., `StoryBridge_X.bmp`, with the
watermark invisibly hidden in the image.

Function `reveal_watermark` accepts the name of a watermarked image file, e.g.,
`BryceCanyon_X.bmp`, and creates a new image file, e.g., `Bryce-Canyon_X_O.bmp`, that reveals the hidden watermark. Note that the watermarked
image file will be distinguished by a ‘_X’ suffix on its filename, and the new file to be
created should have an additional ‘_O’ suffix added.

How would I go about this?

Comment: Your assignment seems pretty clear.  What specifically is giving you trouble with the code you've written so far?

Comment: Oh, I just answered a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16474289/using-pil-to-insert-greyscale-image-into-rgb-image-by-inserting-greyscale-values) which should help you out.